# substring query

Tags: sql, substring

I want to get the substring out of a cell value wrt following eg-

Input: "J.H.Ambani.School"-----------**School**

Output:  "H.Ambani"-----------------**MidName**

That is all the text that comes between the first and the last dots. Length of string  or number of dots in string can be any. I am trying to form a query for above input column "School" to get the output column "MidName".What can be the sql query for it?

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: What about input such as 'a.b.c.d.e.f.school'?

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Database:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(yourColumn, '^[^.]*.|.[^.]*$', '') AS yourAlias
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If is correctly understood your problem by your statement 
**"That is all the text that comes between the first and the last dots"**. Then below is solution to your problem is as given below. Below is working solution in SQL SERVER, for other databases i could not check because of lack of time.

@SourceString : this is your input

@DestinationString : this is your output

```
declare @SourceString varchar(100)='J.H.Ambani.School'
declare @DestinationString varchar(100)
;with result as
(
select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by (select 100))SNO,d from(
select t.c.value('.','varchar(100)')as d from
(select cast('<a>'+replace(@SourceString,'.','</a><a>')+'</a>' as     xml)data)as A cross apply data.nodes('/a') as t(c))B
)
select @DestinationString=COALESCE(@DestinationString+'.','')+ISNULL(d,'') from result where SNO>(select top 1 SNO from result order by SNO)
and SNO<(select top 1 SNO from result order by SNO desc)

select @DestinationString
```